# for loop update list in python is not working

Tags: python, list, loops, append, element

```
a=[[1]]

current=a[-1]
a.pop(-1)
edge=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for j in range(len(edge)-1,-1,-1):
   current.append(edge[j])
   print(current)
   a.append(current)
   current.pop(-1)
```

above code gives me a=[[1],[1],...,[1]], but I thought that s=[[1,10],[1,9],...,[1,2]]..I thought that python read the code from the beginning so those code is correct..could you tell me how to get a=[[1,10],[1,9],...,[1,2]]? thanks in advance!
(I added print(current)<<this line to check whether it is appended correctly and it is actually adjusted correctly and gave me [1,10] but when a.append(current) it is added as [1].)

Comment: You keep spending the same list to `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `a.append(current)` to `a.append(current.copy())`, when you add `current` to `a` the reference of object is added and when you pop the last item of `current` also the item in `a` is changed.
The another way is:
Solution 1:

```python
   a.append(current.copy())
   current.pop(-1)
```

Way 2:

```python
   a.append(current)
   current = [1]
```

Result of  `print(a)`:

```python
[[1, 10], [1, 9], [1, 8], [1, 7], [1, 6], [1, 5], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2]]
```